# Fancytree remove blue border when selected

Tags: javascript, css, fancytree

Using fancytree, how can I prevent the boundary around the fancytree div from becoming blue when it's active?

To replicate, go to the link below, click inside the fancytree control (click any node) and the light gray dotted border gets a blue highlight. No good!

http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-configurator.html
https://github.com/mar10/fancytree

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the style: `outline:none !important;` to either `.fancytree-container` and it won't get the outline around the fancytree

Comment: Thanks, @Alvaro Montoro, though I was confused when you said to add that no-outline element to either  `.fancytree-container`, since I found four in the style-sheet. But I picked the first one (`ul.fancytree-container`), since it seemed most generic and that did the trick...

Answer (score 3):

Little update on this, depending on your version / theme you may also need to disable outline: on .fancytree-treefocus class too, i.e.

```
.fancytree-container {
    border: none !important;
}
.fancytree-treefocus {
    outline: none;
}
```